# Multer req.file is undefined when uploading file?

Tags: iphone, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload pictur from iOS use origin NSUrlsession.

I do not kown why node.js is not work but php works fine.
In node.js

```
app.post('/user/account/avatar', upload.single('avatar.png'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
       console.log(req.file);
       console.log(req.files);
       console.log('body:', req.body);
})
```

The console log:

```
undefined
undefined
body: { '--Boundary-D60C5F57-4786-413C-98B4-9FC89270E1E9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '/Users/liyan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9D529FFD-DB9B-43A3-BA5C-0E4ED346CC00/data/Containers/Data/Application/BCDFF115-EF53-46B7-8FF9-A5A5A87DB046/Documents/avatar.png;filename=avatar.png\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n--Boundary-D60C5F57-4786-413C-98B4-9FC89270E1E9--\r\n' }
```

Comment: multer requires form-multipart

Comment: form-multipart is node npm package or Content-Disposition: form-multipart? I do not found form-multipart npm package

Comment: Read docs of multer